# Spark dataframe returning only structure when connected to Phoenix query server

Tags: apache-spark, jdbc, apache-phoenix

I am connecting to hbase ( ver 1.2) via phoenix (4.11)  queryserver from Spark 2.2.0, but the dataframe is returning the only table structure with empty rows thoug data is present in table.
Here is the code I am using to connect to queryserver.

```
// ---jar ----phoenix-4.11.0-HBase-1.2-thin-client.jar<br>
val prop = new java.util.Properties
prop.setProperty("driver", "org.apache.phoenix.queryserver.client.Driver")
val url = "jdbc:phoenix:thin:url=http://localhost:8765;serialization=PROTOBUF"
val d1 = spark.sqlContext.read.jdbc(url,"TABLE1",prop) 
d1.show()
```

Can anyone please help me in solving this issue. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you are using spark2.2 the better approach would be to load directly via pheonix as a dataframe.This way you would provide the zookeeper url only and you can provide a predicate so that you load only the data required and not the entire data.

```
import org.apache.phoenix.spark._
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

val configuration = new Configuration()
configuration.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "localhost:2181");
val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local").enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
val df=spark.sqlContext.phoenixTableAsDataFrame("TABLE1",Seq("COL1","COL2"),predicate = Some("\"COL1\" = 1"),conf = configuration)
```

Read [this](https://github.com/apache/phoenix/tree/master/phoenix-spark#load-as-a-dataframe-directly-using-a-configuration-object) for more info on getting table as rdd and saving dataframes and rdd's .

Comment: Thanks for the response. as we are ruining hbase in sudo mode we dont have zookeeper url, Hence I went for queryserver jdbc thin clint.

Comment: I am using zookeepr now, also the dataframe code mentioned in https://phoenix.apache.org/phoenix_spark.html. I get this error 
    ConnectionQueryServicesImpl: HConnection established. Stacktrace for informational purposes: hconnection-0x26d820eb java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Unknown Source) <br>

Comment: log 1: ClientCnxn: Socket connection established to habse_remote_ip/habse_remote_ip:2181, initiating session
ClientCnxn: Session establishment complete on server habse_remote_ip/habse_remote_ip:2181,  negotiated timeout = 40000
ConnectionQueryServicesImpl: HConnection established. Stacktrace for informational purposes: hconnection-0x5136207f java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Unknown Source)

Comment: log 2: RpcRetryingCaller: Call exception, tries=10, retries=35, started=50230 ms ago, cancelled=false, msg=row 'SYSTEM:CATALOG,,' on table 'hbase:meta' at region=hbase:meta,,1.1588230740, hostname=localhost,16201,1508176318598
ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: Closing zookeeper sessionid=0x15f28f49b140003
ZooKeeper: Session: 0x15f28f49b140003 closed

Comment: Just to update org.apache.phoenix.spark is working fine when all three spark,hbase and phoenix in one VM or node.                                                                                     but when i use two VM (spark) and in other VM(HBASE & Phoenix) I am getting above error. 2181 is port is open in hbase VM, able to verify via telnet

Comment: If RPC is failing then it could be due to port opening issues . Can you open all ports realting to hbase and phoenix on both the machines.

Comment: See this link for list of ports [here](https://ambari.apache.org/1.2.3/installing-hadoop-using-ambari/content/reference_chap2_4.html).
In centos-7 its done like `sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=<number>/tcp --permanent`

Comment: As phoenix.spark is still not working, I am usinh Hbase rest api which is working. but it uses put and scan method which is slow